# How to add custom body and header to post request on webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, header, android-volley, request-headers

I am implementing an android app where I have to add custom body and header to post request in webview but I'm not getting how to do that. I got the solution that is how to add custom header to post request in webview but I'm not getting how to add custom body to post request in webview. Below is my header and body parameters and url.

Headers:

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length : String.valueOf(params.length())
```

Body Parameters:

```
                JSONObject jsonObjForReqBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjForReqBody.put("Signature", signature);
                jsonObjForReqBody.put("Token", token);
                jsonObjForReqBody.put("Timestamp", timestamp);
                jsonObjForReqBody.put("ServiceCardNumber", svcCardNo);
                jsonObjForReqBody.put("DriverFirstName", person_first_name);
```

Url :

```
https://submittest.glassclaim.com/SelfService/Default.aspx?ClientTag=4E7B1611-E22A-4B38-9651-006CF6DFD71A
```

Using these parameters some data will be pre populated in the loaded form.

Please help me. I have wasted my two days but did not get any solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
String url="https://submittest.glassclaim.com/SelfService/Default.aspx?ClientTag=4E7B1611-E22A-4B38-9651-006CF6DFD71A ";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

            JSONObject jsonObjForReqBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjForReqBody.put("Signature", signature);
            jsonObjForReqBody.put("Token", token);
            jsonObjForReqBody.put("Timestamp", timestamp);
            jsonObjForReqBody.put("ServiceCardNumber", svcCardNo);
            jsonObjForReqBody.put("DriverFirstName", person_first_name);

            String request = gson.toJson(formsDTO);
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webview.loadUrl(url,getHeaders());
```

> Define headers like this

```
private Map<String,String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization","JWT " + loginInfoDTO.getToken());
            return headers;
        }

        private WebViewClient getWebViewClient()
        {

            return new WebViewClient()
            {

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString(), getHeaders());
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url, getHeaders());
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: I can't use 3rd party libraries or even open source libraries(Gson) because of customer limitation. any other solution?

Comment: and also where you used request which is used for conversion of object into json?

Comment: @A.R. if you solve the problem, can you post the solution here ?